# How to rotate an input toggle image properly?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've got a simple input toggle that reveals text when 'toggled'.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/androbaut/pen/GqYVvq)

**HTML**

```
<div class="window">
 <input type="checkbox" id="punch" class="toggle">
  <label for="punch">
   <img class="arrow" src="http://45.79.67.59/moreinfo_arrow.png">
  </label>
 <div>
  <a href="http://codepen.io/"><h3>codepen.io</h3></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.window {
color: #000;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
margin: 0px;
font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}
div.window label{
display: block;
width: 1%;
transition: all 0.75s 0.25s;
transform: rotate(0);
}
input.toggle ~ div {
height: 0px; margin: .1rem;
overflow: hidden;
transition: .6s all cubic-bezier(0.730, -0.485, 0.145, 1.620)
} 
input.toggle:checked ~ div { height: 60px; }
input.toggle:checked + label { transform: rotate(180deg); }
input.toggle { display: none; }
```

When the toggle `<img>` is 'checked', I'd like it to rotate 180˚, however, I've had trouble making the image rotate on it's center axis. It currently rotates on it's edge: good for eliciting a chuckle... not so good for potential users.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The **origin** of your transformation is not the center of the image. So it rotates about the wrong **reference point**. See the following picture:

[image]

This picture is showing the result of rotating a square using `transform: rotate(45deg)` with different `transform-origin` values.

### Solution

Normally just add **`transform-origin: center center;`** to the `transform` property (but to be honest, that's also the default value).

So your actual problem is that you specified the transition on the parent (of the image) what means it will take the center of the parent. Since you specified the width as `1%` the center isn't the same as the center of the image. So to solve this I've felt free to change this to the width of the image (what is in this case `width:200px;`).

Alternatively you could specify the origin manually with absolute values (in your case `transform-origin:100px 100px;`).

**See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xz4mfvgk/)**.

Comment: Woah, thanks for providing a great explanation & working example!